# Plot iteratively single variable from multiple dataframe using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

i am trying to plot age of all participants from multiple dataframes. I want to plot age from all dataframes into one plot. so the final plot should contain datapoints plotting each age.

Following is piece of code i am trying but it gives be blank plots.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

filelist = glob.glob('/Users/kadb/Desktop/participants_tsv_files/*.tsv')
# fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
# ax.xaxis.set_ticks(df.index)
# ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(df['g'])
plt.figure()
for file in filelist:
    df = pd.read_table(file)
    if 'age' in df.columns:
        df['age'] = pd.to_numeric(df['age'])
#         df['age'] = df['age'].astype(str).convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
#         plt.plot(df['age'], 3)
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            if type(row['age']) is int:
                if row['age'] >= 0:
                    age = row['age']
                    plt.plot(age,10)
```

example tsv file:

```
participant_id  gender  age physioSampling  restAcquisiotion
sub-01  M   26  50  after_cuedSGT
sub-02  M   21  50  after_cuedSGT
sub-03  M   22  50  after_cuedSGT
sub-04  M   23  50  after_cuedSGT
sub-05  M   21  50  before_cuedSGT
sub-06  M   19  50  before_cuedSGT
sub-07  F   18  50  before_cuedSGT
sub-08  F   21  50  before_cuedSGT
sub-09  M   20  40-60   before_cuedSGT
sub-10  F   21  50  before_cuedSGT
sub-11  F   20  50  before_cuedSGT
sub-12  M   21  50  before_cuedSGT
sub-13  F   31  50-60   before_cuedSGT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the file cannot be read in correctly. Try using

```
pd.read_table(f, delim_whitespace=True)
```

You're creating the subplot before creating the figure. This needs to be reversed.

Next, what if `type(row['age'])` is not `int`?

If you can make sure that `row['age']` contains `int`s, the next problem would be that you're trying to plot a single point as a line plot.

Use

```
plt.plot(age,10, marker="o")
```

such that the point has a marker attached to it, which can be shown.

In total it seems the code can be made much more compact; so the following should give you what you need.

```
u = u"""participant_id  gender  age physioSampling  restAcquisiotion
sub-01  M   26  50  after_cuedSGT
sub-02  M   21  50  after_cuedSGT
sub-03  M   22  50  after_cuedSGT
sub-04  M   23  50  after_cuedSGT
sub-05  M   21  50  before_cuedSGT
sub-06  M   19  50  before_cuedSGT
sub-07  F   18  50  before_cuedSGT
sub-08  F   21  50  before_cuedSGT
sub-09  M   20  40-60   before_cuedSGT
sub-10  F   21  50  before_cuedSGT
sub-11  F   20  50  before_cuedSGT
sub-12  M   21  50  before_cuedSGT
sub-13  F   31  50-60   before_cuedSGT"""

import io
import pandas as pd
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


filelist = [io.StringIO(u)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for f in filelist:
    df = pd.read_table(f, delim_whitespace=True)
    if 'age' in df.columns:
        #df = df[df["age"] != "n/a"] # remove n/a values or
        df = df[~df["age"].isin(["n/a"])]
        plt.plot(df['age'], [3]*len(df), marker="o", ls="")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: i have added an example tsv file

Comment: how can i avoid converting `n/a` to a numeric value

Comment: What numeric value should `n/a` be?

Comment: So this solution is ploting each dataframe but not all dataframes together into one plot

Comment: remove n/a from plotting.

Comment: I mean, my intention is to plot age column of all files in filelist on one plot. is it plotting only age column from one file at a time

Comment: No, the code above plots the data from all files to the same plot.

Comment: gives error 
`TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-9d1a741d8377> in <module>()
      4     df = pd.read_table(f, delim_whitespace=True)
      5     if 'age' in df.columns:
----> 6         df = df[df["age"] != "n/a"] # remove n/a values
      7         plt.plot(df['age'], [3]*len(df), marker="o", ls="")
      8 
`

Comment: TypeError: invalid type comparison

Comment: Maybe a different approach `df = df[~df["age"].isin(["n/a"])]`.

Comment: how can i also plot histogram of age of all participants. I tried concatenating age column of all dataframes into one col but not success

Comment: how can i also plot histogram of age from all dataframes together into one hist. I tried concatenating age column of all dataframes into one col but no success

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how SO works. This is not a chatroom or forum. You ask a question with all information in it and someone gives an answer. So if you have a question, ask a question. But make sure to have searched for a solution previously and include all necessary details in the question.